# updating a submodule to most recent commit

Tags: git, bash, version-control, git-submodules

I have added a couple of sub-module to my xcode project. How do I upgrade those libraries? For now the way I do it is by going to my Third Party folder, and inside say I have AFNetworking and I just do a pull from there. Not sure if this is the most effective way to do it. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it. You need to be in the repository to update it. Since it is perfectly valid to develop within a submodule, git will not muddle with it from the outside repository in such a way.

you want to

```
cd mysubprojectpath && git pull --ff-only && cd - && git add mysubprojectpath
```

you'll have this in your history. Every time you want to do this, all you have to do is hit `ctrl-R` and start typing `mysubprojectpath` to do it again. Hit enter as soon as it gets the right line from history.